# CTRL+C / CTRL+V don't work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

It's a very weird behavior. My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> keyboard shortcuts are not being called in my **Juno Eclipse**. I know it is somewhat broad... But I'm really lost. I'm using Ubuntu 12. Can it be a OS configuration issue?

Comment: Is this repeatable if you close and restart Eclipse?

Comment: Does Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V work in any other program you have?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in other applications. And it occurs sometimes, inside Eclipse, even if I close/open it.

Comment: I'm wondering if it can be a thead issue from Juno Eclipse, or a bad configuration from OS. Times ago, I used to program on Win7/IndigoEclipse and I never experienced this...

Comment: Same issue, Juno, Win8. Also now right click won't work. Not reliably repeatable, just happens sometimes (like twice a day).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've searched a little bit here and I found an interesting issue: my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> command is being called, but in WRONG file! I gonna explain: I'm programming two different projects, in which both have files with same name. When I open both, and try write on them, Eclipse becomes confused and calls command only in one of they. I have unsuccessfully **pasted** from clipboard in one, and time later I've found the **pasted** commands in the other file! Very weird issue. Now I wonder that it can be a **workspace** bug from Eclipse.

Comment: This happens to me too but you do not have to have files of the same name in different WSs. Not sussed out the pattern yet but it is very confusing

Comment: did you report this ?

Comment: Unbinding Ctrl+C, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V fixes this issue.  Let Windows handle copy/pasting :)

Comment: @ashishduh this should be the answer (btw, i have used your solution)

Answer (score 15):

On my Eclipse, only <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> did not work all the time, especially when Eclipse was running for long time. Then <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> just pasted previously copied text.

What worked for me is to unbind CTRL+C in Eclipse Preferences (General -> Keys). Then the issue never showed up again.

Comment: Using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in Project Explorer might not work anymore.

Comment: For me it was also necessary to restart eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me without even restarting eclipse.

Comment: Thank you so much, it kept copying the terminal output instead of the code :P

Answer (score 4):

You have installed the Android Development Tools and you experience [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34630).

Answer (score 2):

Dave's fix of removing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from eclipse preferences (Window->Preferences->General->Keys : filter for '<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>', click 'Unbind Command') also worked for me.  Thanks Dave!

The 'Copy' function continues to work, even though it is not listed in the preferences list.

Note I was running Eclipse 3.7.2 with CDT 8.0.2.201202111 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the exact same issue.

It started after installing the Swordfish plugin so I tried uninstalling it and it's back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the case in the following scenario :

You have assigned the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> to close a project. It is perfeclty possible. I found the shortcut convenient and easy to remember.

But the shortcut has a side effect to invalidate the <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> which does the copy.

In other words, and IMHO, eclipse does allow us to use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> but it is not well managed... That has an interference on <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

I mean if you type the C and the P quick enough it should be different than only to type the C alone...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when CAPS LOCK was on.