# Worklight v6.0 - Eclipse Studio Hanging

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm using the WL 6.0 with JQuery Mobile 1.3.2 and have found a few issues.

1. JQuery Widgets do not show in the palette.
2. Eclipse starts hanging every half-an-hour or so.
3. Every half-an-hour of usage, the copy-paste,delete and comment keyboard functions stop working.

On restart of Eclipse, things become normal again.

I've tried all the tricks of increasing memory in eclipse.ini, still no cigar. I'm aware of someone else having faced this too, so its not an isolated issue.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I would be interested in knowing what the issue for the 3th point is, I have this behaviour very often. Sometimes to pasting with CTRL+V also pastes in a different window than the current active window. (Windows 8 64bit, Eclipse Juno SR2 x64 bit).

Comment: A few questions back: If you use a version lower than jQuery Mobile 1.3.2, do they show in the palette? What Operative System are you currently using?

Comment: Haven't tried anything below jQuery Mobile 1.3.2. The OS is Win 7 Ultimate 64bit, Eclipse Juno JEE SR2 64Bit

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue that the jQuery Mobile Widgets didn't show in the Palette using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2. I tried jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 and that brought the widgets in the Palette.

My dev environment is:
Eclipse Juno
WL 6.0
Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Number 3 is an Eclipse workbench issue. This is not only related to Worklight, but to Eclipse itself, look here: [CTRL+C / CTRL+V don't work in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613468/ctrlc-ctrlv-dont-work-in-eclipse)